# Django Multiple Inheritance avoid, method conflict

Tags: django

```
class Piece(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(Piece):
    article_piece = models.OneToOneField(Piece, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
    ...

class Book(Piece):
    book_piece = models.OneToOneField(Piece, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
    ...

class BookReview(Book, Article):
    pass
```

Im looking at some documentation, it said that the above code can be used to provide additional fields and methods to BookReview without any conflicts
Im getting the error `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'article_piece' to article without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 2`

What would the default even be and what instance of article_piece, book_piece would i use when instantiating BookReview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message showed-up bacuase you for `Article` model didn't specify that field `article_piece` could be [NULL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#null) in your database. Thus Django asking you to provide a default value (basically assign any `Piece` record to this field) or manage this by your own.

If this was not expected then just allow this field to be null (also blank to so that it will be not required by forms):

```
article_piece = models.OneToOneField(Piece, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
```

Comment: Hi, i thn get the error:
ERRORS:
polls.Article.article_piece: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.

Comment: You can add `primary_key=False` to this field if the model do have another field used as primary key.

Comment: I think by default relationship fields produce primary_key on that field

Comment: The whole point of this was to move the primary key to the top level field, by adding another primrary key to each Article or Book field escapes the purpose

Comment: Im confused as to why the documentation thinks it works:
In my case:
I cant create a migration for Article or Book because what default instance to provide?
Cannot set null=True, blank=True because of primary_key
Adding alternative primary_key escapes the whole purpose of the top level base field which should hold the primary_key

Comment: Yes, that's why you need or to have another field as PK for `Article` model, or drop all existing raws, or assign an `Piece` to existing `Article` records (option (1) that Django offer to you)

Comment: That escapes the purpose of this technique of relationship field for avoiding conflict. 
I could just create 2 mixin classes with different primary_keys which dont collide

Comment: And not inherit from a Base class and assign a relationship field to it

Comment: And so you got back with what Django offer - you already have some records in `Article` and since they now bounded one-to-one with `Piece` you need to assign a `Piece` record (let's say PK) to all `Article` records you already have. Django just telling you that `Articles` could not exists without any `Piece` related to them.

Comment: Oh you mean provide 1 instance of base class for the whole duration of Article, Book

Comment: Yes, exactly or just drop all existing articles and books.

Comment: Actually i just reset the whole database, it seems the problem was with the migration files

Comment: I no longer get the error to specify an instance for the OnetoOne fields